# Robust Statistics for Finance with focus on Outliers

Tags: outliers, extreme-value, robust, finance

There's [Robust Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics) with things like using median instead of mean to ignore outliers (usually considered as errors that should be ingored).

> ... Robust statistics are statistics with good performance for data drawn
>   from a wide range of probability distributions, especially for
>   **distributions that are not normal** One motivation is to produce statistical **methods that are not unduly affected by outliers** ...

Is there something similar, **Robust Statistics for Finances**? Where **distributions are also not normal** but the **outliers could be the most important part**. Something like Extreme Value Theory etc?

Comment: If robust statistics addresses non-normality and outliers, why would you need a special robust statistics to address non-normality and outliers in Finance?

Comment: @jbowman robust statistics addresses outliers by ignoring it. Finance is non-normal (like robust statistics) the difference is that outliers (unlike robust statistics) are the most important part.

Comment: I think you have conflated "robust statistics" with "non-normal" to some extent, which is a mistake.   Robust statistics help you deal with a data generating process that isn't what your model assumes, regardless of whether that assumption is "normal".  If all you want to do is deal with non-normality, that doesn't require robust statistics... at this point, it's not clear what you are asking, since "statistics" would seem to be a reasonable answer to your question.

Comment: What about “outliers” interests you? It seems like, rather than ignore them, you want to emphasize them more than conventional statistical methods do.

Comment: @Dave outliers could be interesting 1) if calculating risk of margin call, or 2) trying to find the peak price to sell, or 3) study a trading strategy when majority of bets are small losses and small minority of bets are huge wins.